# Solving the differential equation $x^3y''+2x^2y-6xy = 0$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

First question on here, so I hope I'm doing this right.
I've been reading up on differential equations lately and have now stumbled upon one that I have no idea how to solve.

$x^3y''+2x^2y-6xy = 0$ 
$y(1)=2$ 
$y'(1)=-1$

I've gotten fairly confident with differential equations of the type $ay'' + by' + cy = f(x)$, but I can't figure out how to work with this expression.

If someone could point me into the right direction I would be very thankful! I don't have much of an attempted solution to post as I'm completely lost on this one.
 I would normally start by looking for roots to create the homogenous solution, but I imagine that I have to separate all the occurrences of x to the other side before I can do that. Without those, I would start by finding the roots with $p(r)=r^2 + 2 - 6$ leading to $r= \sqrt{4}$. I imagine I need to do something entirely different for this one though.

Comment: Is the middle term $2x^2y$ supposed to be a $2x^2y'$? If it is then this is easily solvable by hand. Otherwise wolfram tells me that the solution involves Bessel functions. What tools have you learned in your class? For instance are you familiar with the method of solving differential equations by power series?

Comment: If that $2x^2y$ is supposed to be $2x^2y'$, it's an Euler (or Cauchy-Euler) differential equation.

Comment: It's supposed to be $2x^2y$, not $2x^2y'$. This isn't something that I've learned in classes. I'm going quite a bit beyond it on my own.

Comment: With a limited knowledge of special functions your best bet is probably to assume a power series solution and try to get a recursion for the coefficients. This is a very common powerful approach to solving a completely unknown ODE. In fact many special functions are just the series solutions to some differential equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is $$x^3y''+(2x^2-6x)y = 0, \quad \text{or}$$ $$y''+\left(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)y = 0 \tag{1}$$

This is a type of [Bessel Differential Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html).

We will derive a general result by assuming a solution of the form: $$y = x^\gamma[C_1J_n(\alpha x^{\eta})]$$

and then create a second order differential equation that this $y$ solves. This technique is called a transformation of Bessel's equation. After some computation, we find that $y$ solves:

$$y'' - \dfrac{2\gamma-1}{x}y' + \left(\alpha^2\eta^2x^{2\eta-2}+\dfrac{\gamma^2-n^2\eta^2}{x^2}\right)y = 0 \tag{2}$$

The solution to this (for integer $n$) is $$y = x^{\gamma}[C_1J_n(\alpha x^{\eta})+C_2Y_n(\alpha x^{\eta})]. \tag{3}$$

The next step is to make $(2)$ look like your differential equation. To find your equation simply set $\gamma = \frac{1}{2}$, $\eta = \frac{1}{2}$, $\alpha = 2\sqrt{2}$ and $n = 5$.

Using this, the solution to your equation is

$$y = \sqrt{x}[C_1J_{5}(2\sqrt{2x}) + C_2Y_{5}(2\sqrt{2x})].$$

All that is left is to find the constants.

Answer (score 3):

$\require{cancel}$
Probably the OP did a typo and the ODE is 
$$x^3y''+2x^2y'-6xy=0$$
First we look for a solution of the ODE on the form $x^n$ so we find

$$n(n-1)x^{n+1}+2nx^{n+1}-6x^{n+1}=0\iff n^2+n-6=0$$
so $n=2$ and then $y:x\mapsto \lambda x^2$ is a solution. Now let the function $z$ such that $y(x)=z(x)x^2$ so $y'=z'x^2+2xz$ and $y''=z''x^2+4xz'+2z$ hence we find

$$x^5z''+4x^4z'+\cancel{2x^3z}+2x^4z'+\cancel{4x^3z}-\cancel{6x^3z}=0\iff z''+6xz'=0$$
Now let $u=z'$ so the last ODE becomes $u'+6xu=0$ and then $ u=Ce^{-3x^2}$ so $z=C_1\int e^{-3x^2}dx+C_2$ and finally
$$y(x)=C_1x^2\int e^{-3x^2}dx+C_2x^2$$

**Edited** If the ODE is
$$x^3y''+(2x^2-6x)y=0$$
so let's find a solution expanded on power series
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
hence we find
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n+1}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+2}-6\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+1}=0\tag 1$$
and by changing the index
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty (n-2)(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n}+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2} x^{n}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1} x^{n}=0$$
so$$(n^2-3n-4)a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}=0\iff a_{n-1}=-\frac{2}{(n+1)(n-4)}a_{n-2}$$
hence
$$a_{n}=-\frac{2}{(n+2)(n-3)}a_{n-1}\tag2$$
we can find from $(1)$ the value of $a_0,a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$ and we express by induction from $(2)$ $a_n$ as function of $n$ for $n\ge4$.

Comment: The OP has clearly stated that he did not make a typo. This issue was addressed with another answer that has been deleted.

Comment: @Spencer You might find that many people will leave a comment with corrections or improvements for an answer, and then downvote if the answerer isn't responsive (rather than immediately downvoting).

Comment: @user61527, I downvote answers which are incorrect or do not actually answer the question. I also leave feedback explaining the purpose of the downvote. If the the person downvoted is interested in regaining any lost reputation they can either edit their answer to address the issues or they can delete the answer. There is nothing personal involved here. I would rather immediately downvote something wrong than have the OP or someone else leave thinking a wrong answer is correct which has happened when I waited without downvoting.